# Visualizing server script execution in html5

Tags: python, linux, html, shell, pipeline

I have multiple shell scripts, python scripts and installed tools on my SUSE server.
The final objective is met by running all the scripts/tools in a certain sequence.
I wanted to visualize the operation in html5 page where I can represent the scripts as buttons and on clicking them I should be able to see the status and then I perform similar steps to complete my operation and visualize my output on the page.

I am new to this domain and was curious how I can optimally do the same.

Thanks!